# Converting onnx model to sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, onnx

I Originally trained the model with sklearn, which was then converted to onnx. I now want to get the Sklearn model back. The only related thing I can find online is converting onnx to tf-lite.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is exactly the question? is tf-lite enough?
What have you tried so far (show us the code)?

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no way to convert the model from onnx to skl